# Result of AutoCompleteTextView in Android

Tags: android, view, rendering, autocompletetextview

I have an `AutoCompleteTextView` which is using an `ArrayAdapter<android.location.Address>` as its `Adapter`.

The `getView` method of the adapter is iterating over the `Address` `getAddressLine(i)` and building a `String` to set the `View` with.  The problem is once the user clicks on a suggestion, the `toString()` of `Address` gets entered instead of my `String`.  How can I change this behavior?

[This is where it's happening](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.3.4_r1/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.java#837), but I don't know how to change it.  [Here it is suggesting to subclass](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.3.4_r1/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.java#AutoCompleteTextView.replaceText%28java.lang.CharSequence%29)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On line 839, you are calling mFilter.convertResultToString(selectedItem); which is why you are getting the toString() of the address. If you want to enter the string in your view you need to return the value used in your view from this method.

```
Address address = (Address) selectedItem;
return address.getAddressLine(i);
```

Comment: That is one solution, but I wanted to know if I could return the Address itself rather than the String, then have it rendered.  That object (could) have extra meta-data that is important, that you don't want the user to see.

Comment: Seeing that it is an AutoCompleteTextView, I would think it would always return a String. I think you will have to go the route of using the subclass in this case.